# Borderlayout gui adding to borders

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, border-layout

I'm trying to add 3 panels to the border layout only North South and West

something like

```
[A]

     ___  ______________
    |   ||    P2        |
    |   ||______________|
    |P1 | ______________
    |   ||    P3        |
    |___||______________|
```

I try to do something like

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.add(P1, BorderLayout.WEST);
window.add(P2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
window.add(P3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

It ends up like

```
[B]
         ______________
        |    P2        |
        |______________|
         ___
        |P1 |
        |___|
         ______________
        |    P3        |
        |______________|
```

Do I have to add like a gap as the Center to avoid the issue? I tried just putting P2 and P3 into another Big panel and adding, P1 - West and Big Panel- Center is there any other way around this? Or should I just try a different Layout.

Comment: +1 ASCII pictures always brighten my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just the way that `BorderLayout` works; the `NORTH` and `SOUTH` components extend horizontally over and under the `WEST`, `CENTER`, and `EAST` components.

Your system with two `BorderLayout`s is perfectly fine. You could achieve the same thing with  `GridBagLayout` or `MigLayout`, but I'll guarantee you it'd take much longer to implement. Using intermediate panels is a valid way to do things.

Comment: Yea might just end up using the two borderlayouts

Answer (score 0):

JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.add(P1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
window.add(P4, BorderLayout.WEST);

P4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
P4.add(P2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
P4.add(P3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Answer (score 0):

Try a `MigLayout` instead of `BorderLayout`. The code would look like this:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 2, fill"));
add(P1, "span 1 2, grow");
add(P2, "grow");
add(P3, "grow");
```

http://www.miglayout.com

Comment: even easier: add(P1); add(P2, "dock south"); add(P3, "dock west");